# Is there some quantum potential producing exponential eigenvalues?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, schroedinger-equation, potential, eigenvalue

Usual central potentials produce quantum spectra with energy levels going as $n$, $n^2$, $n^3$ and so on, being $n$ the quantum number of the orbit. In the other extreme we have "dirac-delta" potentials which have only a single discrete eigenvalue. I was wondering, what kind of potential do we need for producing an exponential $e^n$ set of discrete eigenvalues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1D potentials, the sequence of bound state energy eigenvalues $E_n$ cannot grow faster than what happens in the case of an [infinite well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box), i.e.  $E_n$ cannot grow faster than $n^2$.

Comment: Note added: This bound also holds in higher dimensions.

Comment: I am still worried because I can manufacture a potential with any arbitrary finite set of bound states. There is some fine convergence magic here.

Comment: Guessing... a finite set of bound states growing exponentially could approximate some potential of "tidal" kind, $V(x) \sim 1/x^2$, couldn't it?

Comment: A negative attractive 1D potential of the asymptotic form $$-V(x) \sim 1/x^2\quad\text{for}\quad |x|\to \infty$$ (where we implicitly assume that a singularity at $x=0$ has been regularized) would lead to exponentially decaying energy levels $$-E_n \sim e^{-\mu n}\quad\text{for}\quad n\to \infty.$$ This potential is also discussed in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16327/2451) Phys.SE answer.