# Is having full information about the resonances of a rigid body equivalent to having full information about its material parameters?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fourier-transform, oscillators, rigid-body-dynamics

Lets say I have a mechanical system whose mechanical resonances (mode shape and frequency) I can measure with perfect accuracy.  Is this theoretically equivalent to knowing the materials parameters, including spatial variation, with perfect accuracy?  My intuition says that the answer is yes, but I am not sure how to prove it.  For concreteness, here is a specific example.

Given a right circular cylinder such as the one shown below; will measurements of its resonant modes allow me to reconstruct its spatially non-uniform Young modulus and Poisson ratio?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22735/2451 Related quantum mechanical inverse scattering [problem](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13480/2451).

Comment: An initial thought, that I'll try to turn into a full answer later: This sounds suspiciously like the tomography problem. That might give you at least a partial answer.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for the links.  The problem of hearing the shape of a drum is slightly different than what I am interested in.  My question in the parlance of a drum would be: Given the shape of the drum can one infer the material parameters of the skin from the sound?

Comment: @Qmechanic [This text](http://www6.cityu.edu.hk/rcms/publications/ln10.pdf) from one of the answers to the inverse scattering problem which you linked has a more analogous problem.  They study the ability to recover the non-uniform mass density of a vibrating string from its spectra.  It turns out that "the spectra for two sets of boundary
conditions are necessary and suﬃcient to determine [the mass density uniquely]."

Comment: If the material is linear elastic, the free-vibration modes are the eigenvalues of a system that has the form  $K(x) u(x) - \omega^2 M(x) u(x) = 0$.  You question appears to be the following: If you know the mode amplitudes $u(x)$ and the frequencies $\omega$ can you find $K(x)$ and $M(x)$? The problem appears to be ill-posed at first glance but regularization techniques could possibly be used to arrive at a rough solution.