# semiclassical exact expression (in one dimension only)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, approximations, partition-function

let be $ N(x)= \sum_{n} H(x-E_{n}) $ the eingenvalue 'staircase' function

and let be a system so $ V(x)=V(-x)$ and $ V^{-1}(x)=\sqrt \pi \frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}} N(x) $

then would it be true that the two function

$\sum_{n}exp(-tE_{n})=Z(t)= \int_{0}^{\infty}dN(x)exp(-tx) $

and $ \int_{0}^{\infty}dx\int_{0}^{\infty}dpexp(-tp^{2}-tV(x))=U(t) $

would be equal ?? i have just compared the two results

$\int_{0}^{\infty}dnN(x)exp(-tx)=\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\int_{0}^{\infty}dpexp(-tp^{2}-tV(x)) $

i have taken the Laplace transform inside and get the desired result assuming that the potential V(x) is EVEN

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in general *No,* for various reasons.

1. The [WKB approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation) is generally *not* exact for a finite energy-level $N$.
2. Point 1 is true even if we include the metaplectic correction from the [Maslov index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslov_index#Maslov_index).
3. OP's sought-for formula is not exact for a finite energy-level $N$ even for the simple [quantum harmonic oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) (SHO). (This is despite the fact that the WKB approximation with the metaplectic correction famously yields the exact SHO spectrum.) To derive the correct parabolic potential via the fractional derivative formula$^1$, one should use an $N(E)$ function that is affine in the energy $E$, not the staircase function $N(E)=\sum_n \Theta(E-E_n)$. (Of course in the harmonic oscillator case, the staircase function can be approximated by an affine function in the continuum limit.)

--

$^1$See e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16325/2451) for more details.

Comment: umm is still 'incorrect' even if we add the SMOOTH and FLUCTUATING correction to the eigenvalue staircase ??, but as an approximation this is still valid isn't it ? thanks :)