# Finding the Hamiltonian for which a certain wavefunction is the ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian

Consider a 1D system that has the Hamiltonian $H=\frac{P^2}{2m}+V(x)$. At a certain moment, its wavefunction is $\psi$ and has energy $E$. Can we find another Hamiltonian $H'=\frac{P^2}{2m}+V_{eff}(x)$ for which $\psi$ is its ground state with ground state energy $E$?

Note: I know that the $\psi$ is an eigenstate of the operator $\rho H$  with an eigenvalue $E$ where $\rho$ is the density matrix. It is not clear to me though whether this matrix can be represented in the form $\frac{P^2}{2m}+V_{eff}(x)$ or whether $\psi$ is its ground state.

EDIT: Since the ground state of a Hermitian $H'$ is a real function while $\psi$ is complex function, then I release the requirement of the ground state of $H'$ to be the best approximation to $\psi$

Comment: What about the Hamiltonian for the 1-D Harmonic Oscillator?

Comment: It sounds to me as if you're effectively asking for the [Hohenberg-Kohn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory#Hohenberg.E2.80.93Kohn_theorems).

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to reconstruct the Hamiltonian from knowledge of its ground state wave function?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/269563/) and [In quantum mechanics, given certain energy spectrum can one generate the corresponding potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13480/)

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is no. For example, [Ground state wavefunctions in 1d have no nodes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_state#1D_ground_state_has_no_nodes) So even if the wavefunction $\psi$ has a node anywhere, there is no $V_{eff}$ for which it is a ground state.