# Dependence of energy $E$ with principal quantum number $n$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, potential, schroedinger-equation, semiclassical

Is there any way to tell how the energy levels of a potential well depend upon the quantum number $n$, looking at the potential, before solving?

- I mean, for harmonic oscillator, $E\sim n$, for infinite square well, $E\sim n^2$, so, can it be guessed how it would be for a power law potential $\sim x^p$, where $p$ is some power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may show, using semiclassical WKB methods explained in e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16325/2451), that
the discrete energy levels go as
$$ E_n ~~\propto~~{\rm sgn}(p)~ n^{\frac{1}{1/p+1/2}}, \qquad n\in\mathbb{N}, $$ 
for a 1D potential $$ \Phi(x)~~\propto~~{\rm sgn}(p)~|x|^p,
\qquad -2~<~p~\leq~\infty .$$

Comment: Is there no method to show it directly from schrodinger equation?i am afraid i am not yet familiar with wkb methods.

Comment: FWIW, WKB _is_ a semiclassical approximation to the Schrödinger equation.