# How can you read from a phase space diagram how quickly a path gets traversed?

Tags: coordinate-systems, time, hamiltonian-formalism, oscillators, phase-space

I'm learning about Hamiltonian mechanics and it is quite interesting. However I'm trying to understand how to see how quickly a path in phase space gets traversed. How do you read from a phase space diagram the period or the speed of which a particle travels this phase space path? For example a pendulum:

[image: source: https://www.physicswithelliot.com/simple-pendulum-with-phase-space]

Comment: You get the period from $~\phi(t)~$ and the velocity from the energy conservation $~v^{2}=2Lg\cos\left( \phi  \left( t\right) \right) $

Comment: What is $\phi(t)$?

Comment: The period is the derivative of the area of the orbit with respect to the orbit's energy -- for more look up "action-angle variables", "adiabatic invariants"...

Comment: @Eli energy is not conserved in every system. As an example, you you add a damper or a viscous contribution to the pendulum, energy is not conserved and you get stable equilibria to be actactor points in the phase space with some of the path spiralling into them

Comment: @basics yes but not for this phase diagram there is no damper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find a pair of generalized variable $q$ and its time derivative $\dot{q}$ (or, if you are using 100% Hamiltonian formalism, the generalized momentum associated $p$ to retrieve $\dot{q}$).

Then take a line in the phase-space passing through the point you wish as the initial point of the trajectory, namely the initial conditions of the system $q_k^0$, $\dot{q}_k^0$. This can be written in a parametric form as a function of a parameter $s$

$q_i = Q_i(s;q_k^0, \dot{q}_k^0)$
$\dot{q_i} = \dot{Q_i}(s;q_k^0, \dot{q}_k^0)$

Remembering that $\dot{q} = \dfrac{d q}{dt}$, with a change of variable $s(t)$, it's possible to write

$\dot{q}_i(s) = \dfrac{d q_i}{dt}(s) = \dfrac{d q_i}{d s} \dfrac{d s}{d t} = q_i'(s) \dfrac{ds}{dt}$,

and rearranging separating the variables

$dt = \dfrac{q'_i(s)}{\dot{q}_i(s)}ds$,

and eventually integrating along the path from the initial point identified by
the value of the parameter $s = s_0$ and time $t = t_0$ (related by the change of variable $s_0 = s(t_0)$), to the final point identified by the value $s = s_1$ and time $t = t_1$,

$\Delta t = t_1 - t_0 = \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt = \int_{s_0}^{s_1} \dfrac{q'_i(s)}{\dot{q}_i(s)}ds$.

**Example - small amplitude oscillation of a pendulum.**

Let's do an example on the small amplitude oscillations of a pendulum, to find a solution analytically. We're taking a system whose phase-diagram is the one of your question, and the evolution is described by the small ellipses (in the small oscillation limit), around the origin.

The non-linear equation governing the free evolution of the system reads

$m L^2 \ddot{\theta} + m L g \sin \theta = 0$,

and the linearized equation around the stable equilibrium $\overline{\theta} = 0$ reads

$m L^2 \ddot{\theta} + m L g \theta = 0$$\qquad \rightarrow \qquad$
$\ddot{\theta} + \dfrac{g}{L} \theta = 0$$\qquad \rightarrow \qquad$
$\ddot{\theta} + \Omega \theta = 0$,

being $T = \dfrac{2 \pi}{\Omega}$ the period of the oscillation. Now we can choose $q = \theta$ and define $\dot{q} = \omega$ as the generalized coordinate and its time derivative, and write the second-order ODE as a system of 2 first-order ODEs, namely

$\left\{ \begin{array} \\ \dot{\theta} = \omega  \\  \dot{\omega} =  -\Omega^2 \theta \end{array}\right.$

Now, we have to eliminate time, as an example multiplying the two equations together, to get

$0 = \omega \dot \omega + \Omega^2 \theta \dot{\theta} = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\omega^2 + \Omega^2 \dfrac{1}{2} \theta^2 \right)$,

that tell us that the content of the parentheses is a constant of the motion (its the mechanical energy here), and thus we can write

$2E = \omega^2 + \Omega^2 \theta^2 = \dot{q}^2 + \Omega^2 q^2$.

This is the equation of an ellipse in the phase-space, that can be written in parametric form (put the parametric form into the implicit one as a proof), as

$q(s) = \dfrac{\sqrt{2E}}{\Omega} \cos s$
$\dot{q}(s) = \sqrt{2E} \sin s$.

Now, we are ready to evaluate time between two points on the same line in the phase-space,

$\Delta t = t_1 - t_0 = \displaystyle \int_{t_0}^{t_1} dt = \int_{s_0}^{s_1} \dfrac{q'(s)}{\dot{q}(s)} ds = - \int_{s_0}^{s_1} \dfrac{\frac{\sqrt{2E}}{\Omega} \sin s}{\sqrt{2E} \sin s} ds  = - \int_{s_0}^{s_1} \dfrac{1}{\Omega}  ds = -\dfrac{\Delta s}{\Omega}$.

Few examples:

- full oscillation: $s_1 = s_0 + 2 \pi$, $\Delta t = \frac{2\pi}{\Omega}$,
- half oscillation: $s_1 = s_0 + \pi$, $\Delta t = \frac{\pi}{\Omega}$

Answer (score 3):

For a particle in a 1D potential (i.e. in a 2D phase space), the period $T(E)=A^{\prime}(E)$ is the derivative of the phase space area $A(E)$ of the orbit wrt. the orbit's energy $E$, cf. above comment by knzhou, see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/389454/2451).

If e.g the potential vanishes at $x=0$, then the energy $E=\frac{p(x=0)^2}{2m}$ can be read off from the orbit's intercept with the $p$-axis.

Hence OP's requested information can in principle be geometrically deduced from the phase space diagram.