# One-dimensional Schrödinger equation: reproducing a given set of energy values

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

Given a set of $N$ increasing real numbers $\{E_1, E_n, \cdots, E_N \}$, is it always possible to find a potential $V(x)$ such that the set of $\{E_j\}$ are the lowest eigenvalues of the corresponding one-dimensional Schrödinger equation for given mass?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13480/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Yes, you may always craft a reflection less potential through [SUSYQM](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/037015739400080M) starting from the shallowest level. A quick review you might appreciate is [Kwong & Rosner 1986](https://academic.oup.com/ptps/article/doi/10.1143/PTPS.86.366/1885807).

Comment: thanks! Both the reviews and the previous answer are very relevant. I wonder, though, how 'physical' some of the isospectral potential are. For example, some may have a lot of narrow peaks in order to shift a particular level. I wonder what would happen if we imposed limitations on the derivatives of the potentials to prevent 'peaks' or other near singularities.