# Can energy levels rise faster than $n^2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, asymptotics

For a [1D particle in a box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box), energy levels are exactly proportional to $n^2$.

For the harmonic oscillator, $E_n\sim n$. And for a particle in an $|x|^\alpha$ potential, the energies are $\sim n^\beta$ with $\beta <2$ from the [WKB approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation).

I also vaguely recall that the eigenvalues for a regular [Sturm-Liouville problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) are $\sim n^2$.

All of this suggests that the [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) cannot rise faster than $n^2$. Is my intuition correct here?

Comment: Are you restricting attention to 1D potentials?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, I think OP means the principal quantum number "n"

Comment: possibly interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_law

Answer (score 5):

1. In this answer we generalize OP's 1D semiclassical WKB estimate for a power law potential $\Phi(x) \propto |x|^{\alpha}$ to an arbitrary potential $\Phi(x)$. If $\ell(V)$ denotes the accessible length function at potential energy-level $V$, then the number of bound states $N(E)$ below energy-level $E$ is
   $$ N(E) ~\approx ~\frac{\sqrt{2m}}{h} \int_{V_0}^E  \frac{\ell(V)~dV}{\sqrt{E-V}},\tag{2} $$
   cf. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16325/2451).
   Since $V\mapsto \ell(V)$ is a monotonically (weakly) increasing non-negative function, we can pick a potential energy-level $V_1>V_0$ such that
   $$ N(E) ~\gtrsim~\frac{\sqrt{2m}}{h} \int_{V_1}^E  \frac{\ell(V_1)~dV}{\sqrt{E-V}} ~=~\frac{2\sqrt{2m}}{h}  \ell(V_1)\sqrt{E-V_1},$$
   i.e. the number of bound states $N(E)$ grows at least as fast as $\sqrt{|E|}$.

   Or equivalently: $E_n$ grows no faster than $n^2$.
2. On the other hand, from regular [Sturm-Liouville theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory), it is known that the [resolvent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_formalism) is a [compact operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space), which implies that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|E_n|^{-2}~<~\infty$$
   is convergent, and which shows that $E_n$ must grow faster than $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

It sort of depends on what restrictions you impose on $H$.

If we let $|n\rangle$ be the eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator, then you can surely define
$$
H:=\sum_{n\ge0}E_n|n\rangle\langle n|
$$
where $E_n$ is any function you want, say $E_n=n^3$. This Hamiltonian has eigenvalues $E_n$ and eigenfunctions $\psi_n(x)\sim H_n(x)e^{-x^2}$, which are perfectly well-defined wave-functions.

You may even be able to write the above as $P^2+V(x)$ for some nasty $V(x)$, although I haven't tried.

So unless you specify which precise type of Hamiltonian you want, the answer is that you can have any spectrum you want.

Comment: The WKB result from @Qmechanic would seem to indicate that there might be an impediment to realizing this Hamiltonian in the form $P^2 + V$.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert QM's answer applies to sufficiently nice $V$. Although I don't have any particularly convincing argument, I suspect that it is still possible with a sufficiently nasty $V$.